# MacOS Mojave causing permission errors

Tags: permission, mojave, wireshark

Issue: MacOS permissions falsely configured.

Recently I had some networking issues on my mac running High Sierra, so I backed up my disk, completely wiped my mac, installed Mojave and then moved files over that I needed. However since upgrading, I'm getting tons of permission denied errors. For example, when installing some packages from Terminal, I'm forced to use sudo for almost every command as Mac isn't letting programs I install to even create folders... this happened again downloading Wireshark today, Mac wouldn't let Wireshark install properly and would throw back over 40 permission denied errors. I've attached an image from Wireshark, however I'm aware this doesn't count as a "log".[image]

Comment: How did you move these files over? - Did those files include the ~/.config/ folder? - It seems like you have your permissions messed up somehow.

Comment: Also, which permissions are actually set on the files you get the errors for?